# regex + jquery - modify text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

```
<span id="one"><a id="google" href="google.com/">link1</a></span> <br />
<span id="two"><a id="yahoo" href="yahoo.com/">link2</a></span>

<br />
<br />
<span class="click" id=1>click one</span> <br />
<span class="click" id=2>click two</span> <br />
<span class="click" id=3>click three</span> <br />

$(".click").live('click', function() {    
   $("a").attr('href', $("a").attr('href').replace(/\d*$/, $(this).attr('id')));
});
```

If I click for example **click one** then links are:

```
<span id="one"><a id="google" href="google.com/1">link1</a></span> <br />
<span id="two"><a id="yahoo" href="google.com/1">link2</a></span>
```

instead of:

```
<span id="one"><a id="google" href="google.com/1">link1</a></span> <br />
<span id="two"><a id="yahoo" href="yahoo.com/1">link2</a></span>
```

**LIVE EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/wtAbp/14/

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is working sample http://jsfiddle.net/wtAbp/18/

```
$(".click").live('click', function() {  
    var $id = $(this).attr('id');
    $("a").each(function() {
        $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace(/\d*$/, $id));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `$("a")` instead of `$(this)`

```
$(".click").live('click', function() {    
   $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace(/\d*$/, $(this).attr('id')));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".click").live('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $("a").each(function() {
        $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace(/\d*$/, id));
    });
});
```

Cheer ^^

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that when you click one it replaces the values on all a elements. Try this:

```
<span id="one"><a id="google" href="google.com/">link1</a></span> <br />
<span id="two"><a id="yahoo" href="yahoo.com/">link2</a></span>

<br />
<br />
<span class="click" id=1>click one</span> <br />
<span class="click" id=2>click two</span> <br />
<span class="click" id=3>click three</span> <br />

$(".click").live('click', function() {    
    var $this = $(this);
    $.each("a", function(index, element) {
              $(element).attr('href',            $(element).attr('href').replace(/\d*$/, $this.attr('id')));
    });

});
```